# Оптимизация работы с БД

Tags: php, mysql, mvc

Есть таблицы товаров, их свойств и их значений. Значения хранятся в разных таблицах, в зависимости от их типа. Например, это могут быть сотрудники, адреса, размеры товаров и т.д.

Нужно вывести список товаров со всеми свойствами и их значениями.

Поскольку значения свойств хранятся в разных таблицах, в один запрос не уместить. Для каждого свойства система обращается к базе и вытаскивает нужное значение.
В итоге получается куча запросов к одной и той же таблице, но к разным строкам.

В теории просто — нужно собрать все нужные таблицы, один раз обратиться к базе и записать их в память. Потом обращаться не к базе, а к памяти.

Но как это сделать на практике, в рамках mvc? 
Есть модель в которой реализована связь параметра с его значением. Как сделать так, чтобы при первом обращении к модели, она обращалась к базе, а при последующих вызовах — к переменной с результатом первого запроса?

Comment: Чем JOIN не угодил?

Comment: а join не вариант?

Comment: Если хочешь кешировать, используй в проекте noSQL решения или все тот же memcached

Comment: Название таблицы из которой брать данные неизвестно, оно хранится в таблице с параметром. Динамически же нельзя изменить запрос в зависимости от поля

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать сделать так. Первым запросом мы определяем какие данные из каких таблиц и по каким ключам получаем. Формируем запросы, по одному на таблицу с данными и загружаем данные. Далее берем данные из памяти.